# function from non separable normed space $X$ onto separable normed space $Y$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Can you please give me a simple example of linear continuous mapping from non separable normed space $X$ onto separable normed space $Y$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider maps from $\ell_\infty\oplus_1\ell_1$ to $\ell_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a non-separable normed space.

If $Y$ is finite dimensional, then for *every* non-separable space $X$ the answer to your question is positive. Since $Y$ is finite dimensional it is, of course, separable. Consider arbitrary closed subspace $X_0\subset X$ with codimension equal to $\mathrm{dim}(Y)$. Since this dimensions are finite you have a lot of ismorphisms between $X/X_0$ and $Y$. Lets take one $I:X/X_0\to Y$. Consider standard projection $\pi :X\to X/X_0$, then the desired map is $T=I\circ \pi$. It is linear continuous and surjective as composition of continuous surjective linear maps.

If $Y$ is separable and infinite dimensional then for *some* non-separable spaces $X$ the answer to your question is positive. The easiest example (provided by David Mitra) is the following: take $X=\ell_\infty\oplus_1 Y$ and consider projection
$$
\pi:\ell_\infty\oplus_1 Y\to Y:(z,y)\mapsto y
$$

In general if $Y$ is infinite dimensional and separable, it is not know whether for *arbitrary* non-seprable $X$ there exist surjective operator $T:X\to Y$. In fact this question is related to the following well known open "separable quotients problem":
$$
\text{ Does every Banach space have separable quotient }
$$
$$
\text{ by closed subspace of infinite codimension? }
$$
There are wide classes of non-separable Banach spaces whose quotients are separable. For details see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67808/separable-quotients-of-non-separable-banach-spaces) on mathoverflow.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what is meant.  Finite codimension does not imply closed.  E.g., if you take a discontinuous linear operator onto a finite dimensional space, its kernel is finite codimensional and not closed.  However, if the range of a continuous linear operator is finite codimensional then it is closed.

Comment: @JonasMeyer, so I'll just require closedness. Is it true that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exist closed subspaces with codimension $n$?

Comment: I guess you can take linearly independent $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n\in X^*$ (e.g. using Hahn-Banach), define $T:X\to\mathbb C^n$ by $T(x)=(\varphi_1(x),\ldots,\varphi_n(x))$, and let $X_0=\ker T$.

Comment: So, my argument works... Thanks, Jonas you always help me so much!

Comment: Why not state it positively: does every Banach space have a separable infinite-dimensional quotient (by a closed subspace)?

Comment: @t.b. Edited${}$

Answer (score 6):

Let $X=\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$, $Y=\mathbb{C}$. Define $\varphi:X\to Y$ by 
$$
\varphi(x)=x(1).
$$

Answer (score 5):

Take any bounded non-zero functional from a non-separable normed space.